# Jquery plugin -- Dynamically bind it to elements

Tags: jquery, plugins, element, bind

I created a jquery plugin, and now I want to bind it to DOM elements which are created by a php script.

Using the following markup as an example:

```
<div class="showcase_window">

<div id='mywhatever'></div>
<div id='mywhatever2'></div>
<div id='mywhatever3'></div>

</div>
```

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#mywhatever').showcase();
    $('#mywhatever2').showcase();
    $('#mywhatever3').showcase();
});
```

But since the markup is created by the php script, I am trying to get something like this to work:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.showcase_window').children().on('showcase');

  });
```

But I am a bit confused... I understand that 'on' is used to attach events, but I am not sure how to go about it...

Many thanks!

P.S.: Here is the plugin:

```
 $.fn.showcase = function () {

     return this.each(function() {

      var $this = $(this);

      $this.find(".sc_itm_display").hover(function() {
            $this.find(".sc_img_front").stop(true,true).fadeOut("slow");
            }, function() {
        $this.find(".sc_img_front").stop(true,true).fadeIn("slow");
        });

    $this.find('.sc_color_select img').click(function() {

    var color_path_1 = $(this).attr("src").replace("color","1");
    var color_path_2 = $(this).attr("src").replace("color","2");

    $this.find('.sc_itm_display .sc_img_back img').attr("src",color_path_1);
    $this.find('.sc_itm_display .sc_img_front img').attr("src",color_path_2);

    });
    });
    };
```

Comment: `on` is for events only. not for attach plugin things.

Comment: not sure but try this... $('.showcase_window').children().on({
  click: function() {
   this.showcase();
  }
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on` attaches handlers to events. Events can be user actions or processes completing/failing etc.

You are not attaching an event but a function, in which case jQuery does it for you.

`$('.showcase_window').children()` or simply `$('.showcase_window>div')` contains the three example divs created by your script.

`$('.showcase_window').children().showcase();` (or more efficiently `$('.showcase_window>div').showcase();`)

will execute `showcase()` once for each of these divs. `this` within `showcase` will be the div ('mywhatever') itself.

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP is generating the elements you want to act on, use it to output a script with an string of comma separated id values to target.  Then use those targets for your plugin.

PHP outputs this:

```
var target_ids = "#this, #that, #the_other";
```

in your jQuery:

```
$(target_ids).showcase();
```

Alternately, use a unique class to label all the elements you want to target and you need not know their id.

```
$(".mywhatevers").showcase();
```